# Why isn't this function working on greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Why isn't this function working in greasemonkey.

```
function arre(){
    var index;
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    for (index = 0; index < fruits.length; index++) {
        window.alert(fruits[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Please be more specific. I have left my glass sphere at home. :-)

Comment: I forgot to call the function, was new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just declared the function but did not call it.
Just add to the end:

`arre();`

Comment: Yeah maybe he forget to call it. But maybe he had called it and get an error. He should give some feedback for all other later readers to be more specific. :-)